# How to get type data in TypeScript decorator?

Tags: typescript, decorator

I would like to be access the type information on a variable declaration that I want to decorate:

```
@decorator
foo: Foo;
```

From the decorator, can I somehow access `Foo`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should be able to do it, but you'll need to use [reflect-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata).

There's an example here: [Decorators & metadata reflection in TypeScript: From Novice to Expert](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-4) which seems to be exactly what you're after:

```
function logType(target : any, key : string) {
    var t = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
    console.log(`${key} type: ${t.name}`);
}

class Demo{ 
    @logType
    public attr1: string;
}
```

Should print:

> attr1 type: String

Comment: When I do `import 'reflect-metadata';` and `import 'zone.js/dist/zone'`, I get the message `Cannot resolve all parameters for 'App'(?, ?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'App' is decorated with Injectable.`. Any ideas? I am on RC1.

Comment: Is that compilation error or runtime? I'm able to compile the above example with no issues, so it must be something to do with this `zone.js` thing. I added `import "zone.js/dist/zone"` and recompiled with no issues as well.

Comment: Thanks Nitzan for providing useful link. I was wandering for the whole day

Comment: BTW. To make the 'design:type' work make sure add `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` in the tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution using **Vite** and **React** TypeScript.

1. Add appropriate decorator compiler options to your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       /* ... */
   }
}
```

2. Install babel plugin dependencies

```
npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
npm install @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
npm install @babel/preset-typescript
npm install babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata
```

3. Apply the necessary babel configuration to your `vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react({
            babel: {
                plugins: [
                    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
                    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
                    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
                ],
                presets: ["@babel/preset-typescript"],
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Now you can test the solution:

```
function Decorator(target: any, key: string) {
    const type = Reflect.getMetadata("design:type", target, key);
    console.log(`Field: ${key} | Type: ${type.name}`);
}

class MyClass {
    @Decorator field1!: string;
    @Decorator field2!: number;
    @Decorator field3!: boolean;
}

// Field: field1 | Type: String
// Field: field2 | Type: Number
// Field: field3 | Type: Boolean
```

Comment: Tried with Vue (I don't think that really matters), but unfortunately this setup does not work. :/