# Typescript: Implementing a transformer to access types at run-time

Tags: typescript

After TSC compiled the TS code to JS, the types are removed and not available anymore.

But, in principle, it should be possible to make the types available at run-time by using a webpack/typescript/Vite transformer.

Has anyone achieved this?

```js
type Data = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

// How can we implement `getType()`?
console.log(getType<Data>());
// It should print:
// { name: 'string', age: 'number' }
```

At compile-type, the type of `Data` is known, so it should be possible (albeit not easy) to implement a transformer that makes the type available at run-time.

This would enable a mirad of uses cases, such as IO validation.

For my use case I don't need advanced types such as generics. I only need the types: object, array, string, number, and date.

Context: I'm building an RPC implementation (https://github.com/brillout/wildcard-api).

**Edit**: I'm not looking for something like [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#basic-usage) where you define a schema with zod and the TypeScript types are then inferred. My users define their types with TypeScript *directly* and I need to know these types at run-time. So I do need a compile-time transformer.

Comment: There are a lot of runtime validators: `ajv, joi, v8n, validate.js`. You should use typescript custom type guards for such purpose

Comment: @captain-yossarian These are JavaScript validators. What I want is to do run-time validation by *only* using the types I defined with TypeScript. (End goal here is to automatically do the validation for my Wildcard API users.)

Comment: But types are removed after compilation

Comment: Have you ever tried with [reflect-metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata)?
You have to map your ```Data``` variable to a class and "decorate" it. After, you can use ```Reflect``` to get the metadata you want. See [this](https://medium.com/jspoint/introduction-to-reflect-metadata-package-and-its-ecmascript-proposal-8798405d7d88) for a better introduction.

Comment: @CarloCorradini I don't think it's part of `Reflect`'s design to make types available at runtime. Sure I could do something like zod but it's not what I'm looking for; I edited my question to clarify what it is I'm looking for.

Comment: @brillout Yes, is designed to achieve this and many more. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38315252/6676781) stack overflow answer :)

Comment: @CarloCorradini Neat. Although it only works for class attributes as function decorators are still work-in-progress. Composite types such as `{ name: string; age: number }` also seem to be still work-in-progress. When both are implemented, I believe `Reflect` will be a viable option for me... neat & thanks for the pointer.

Comment: The best thing you can do right now is using [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) to check each different attribute of a class.

Comment: List of TypeScript runtime type checking tools: https://github.com/akutruff/typescript-needs-types

Answer (score 2):

Is something like [`ts-runtime`](https://github.com/fabiandev/ts-runtime) what you are after? It's not exactly as your question describes but have a look at this.

Your input code:

```
type Data = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};
```

It outputs:

```
import t from "ts-runtime/lib";

const Data = t.type(
  "Data",
  t.object(
    t.property("name", t.string()),
    t.property("age", t.number())
  )
);
```

You can then run:

```
t.type(Data).assert({/* ... obj to evaluate ... */})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `typescript-rtti` project does this comprehensively for all type metadata for a given compilation (and works across packages when both the caller and the callee have been compiled using the transformer). You can test it out from the browser at https://typescript-rtti.org/

(Disclaimer: I am the author)

Answer (score 0):

Try [tst-reflect](https://github.com/Hookyns/tst-reflect).
It is pretty advanced Reflection system for TypeScript, inspired by the C# reflection.

```js
import { getType, Type } from "tst-reflect";

type Data = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

const typeofData: Type = getType<Data>();

const objWithProps = typeofData.getProperties().reduce((res, prop) => {
  res[prop.name] = prop.type.name;
  return res;
}, {} as any);

console.log(objWithProps);
```

**Output**

```
{ name: 'String', age: 'Number' }
```